# How to create separate entities from strings in a text file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm looking for a solution to a rather simple problem:

1. Have a text file with words\strings separated by '\n' Each new string starts after '\n'
2. Need to get each one of those strings out of the file and create a separate entity out of it.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a site where people do your work for you...

Comment: What part exactly is giving you trouble?  Please post some existing code that you have written that demonstrates both your exact intent and the precise problem that you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this task sounds pretty straightforward except for the vague idea of "creat[ing] a separate entity" out of a string (???).

Here is the general algorithm that I would use if I were to implement such a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 0xFF
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  char line[LEN];
  FILE * input_file = NULL;
  if ((input_file=fopen("myinputfile.txt","r")) == NULL) {
    // Handle error when opening the file...
  }
  while (fgets(line, LEN, input_file) != NULL) {
    // Process each line of input...
  }
  fclose(input_file);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the vague description that you gave, what you can do is to use an array (buffer), and in conjunction with a fopen, a loop, and sscanf, you can match the results of the file and put them into separate elements within the array. Then you can access the results. You'll likely need to track some indices.

There's a bunch of other ways that you can do this, but more information is definitely needed.